# Subscribe is firing when data were not changed in store

Tags: angular, ngrx, reselect

I have and Angular 5 app with ngrx. I have an array of objects in store. When I subscribe to get this array change event is fired even when I don't change **state.details.selectedOptions.** I changed only **state.details.page** and subscriber was called.

When I change **state.details.selectedOptions** to plain value (string) everything is working as expected. As I see the problem is in arrays/nested elements?

```
//store
const initialState = {
  page: null,
  selectedOptions: []
}
// selector
export const selectedOptionsSelector =  createSelector(
  (state: any) => state.details.selectedOptions
)
// also tried such variant
export const selectedOptionsSelector = (state: any) => state.details.selectedOptions
// Component
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.select(selectedOptionsSelector).subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log('selectedOptions', res)
  })
}
```

**Update:**

Basically in my case I always have empty array in selectedOptions because initial state didn't change. I tried using distinctUntilChanged in select but it didn't help

Comment: your description is very poor, but it may be a problem with primitives and instances, as you may notice `"abc" === "abc"`, but `["abc"] !== ["abc"]`, so basically every time you use `{...}` or `[...]` you are creating a new instance, using `rxjs` operators like `distinct` may be find as a very useful here as it allows to compare new and current value and emit new value only if it differs from the previous one using your custom comparison function

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know for sure as you have not added your reducer definition, but as you say you always set selectedOptions to an empty array I will assume you mean in your reducer you have an action to update the page, and when the action is dispatched you modify its state as:

```
case Actions.Type.UPDATE_PAGE: {
    return {
        ...state,
        page: 'newValue',
        selectedOptions: []
    }
}
```

Redux uses shallow equality checking to determine if the state has changed. As @Roomy says, ["a"] === ["a"]returns false, therefore Redux will see the above as a change to state.selectedOptions as you are assigning a new reference.
Using distinctUntilChanged() doesn't make a difference because it uses shallow equality checking, so if you pass 2 arrays with different references, it will consider this a change.

If you only need to update the page, update only the page property and leave selectedOptions as it was:

```
case Actions.Type.UPDATE_PAGE: {
    return {
        ...state,
        page: 'newValue'
    }
}
```

This way the observer in your component won't be notified of a change in selectedOptions.

You could also use

```
case Actions.Type.UPDATE_PAGE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                page: 'newValue',
                selectedOptions: state.selectedOptions
            }
}
```

because in this case selectedOptions would still point to the same reference. This is pointless though, but it helps explaining the point.